# Cheap NAS solution for home usage - ARM or Intel?

Tags: nas, streaming, arm, dlna, intel-atom

Im planning to invest in a NAS solution for home entertainment purposes. My budget is about **200$**, and dedicated NAS offerings with decent performance is often much more expensive than that. The budget does not include the cost of storage.

My requirements are:

- Stream 1080p over DLNA (possibly with transcoding, if 4k is feasable with the hardware, thats a plus but not a requirement)
- Download torrents
- Reasonable power consumption. 5-20W, i dont wan't a power hog. Mobile CPUs are preferable.

As a results, i was planning to install linux on a ARM development board and "build" my own NAS.

As Raspberry PI3 does not offer a dedicated gigabit ethernet i was thinking about [Banana PI M3](http://www.banana-pi.org/m3.html) for around 90$

However, ARM boards have limited support in the grapics department which may be required for DLNA transcoding.

The other alternative im considering is the Voyo V3 which has an Intel SOC with Intel HD graphics and Windows 10. The Aton x7 processor is much faster than the ARM on the Banana PI: [Voyo V3](http://www.gearbest.com/tv-box-mini-pc/pp_292915.html)

If i purchase the Vovy v3 i might run windows as a nas solution with plex or servio as DLNA solution.

Which hardware would best suit my needs? The more powerfull Intel Voyo or the cheap Banana PI? Would the banana PI be sufficient to stream 1080p?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). You could try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You would need a rather powerful CPU if you'd want to do transcoding on the go, especially with that resolution so I'm not sure if the budget will cover both the device and the storage drives.

You could check out a solution such as the [WD My Cloud](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=x6y7Tc)  for simple home usage and even media streaming through DLNA, but it does not offer transcoding. For this you would need to look at something like [WD My Cloud Pro](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=xRdij4) series.

You could check out some solutions online from users that have done it with devices such as the Raspberry Pi.

Building a NAS yourself in a small case could be an option, but you may end up with a lot bigger power consumption.

Are you including your storage drives in your budget? Are you planning on running external or internal drives on that NAS?

Captain_WD.

Comment: Im not including storage in the budget so 200$ without storage!

Comment: In this case some of the pre-build NAS devices will be within your budget, but I doubt you will manage to find something to do transcoding on the go, especially with that targeted resolution. The devices that you listed in your OP should be able to handle your needs if you are willing to go over your budget. :)